# Updated Ubuntu packages, now Apache won't start: (98)Address already in use: AH00072:

Tags: apache2, nginx, restart

I'm running a Vesta Control Panel. After I updated Ubuntu sever packages and restarted the server, my Apache wouldn't start.  When I checked what is occupying the port 80, it was nginx.  How do I fix this problem permanently?

I was able to fix this temporarily by stopping nginx service and starting the apache service.

I'm not sure which files to edit to fix this problem.
Any help appreciated

Edit: Ubuntu 18.04.3 (LTS) x64

Comment: Perhaps you don't need `nginx`. In that case it is best to uninstall it. Try this: `sudo apt remove nginx` and see what *other* packages `apt` will uninstall. If no package rings a bell, you probably don't need `nginx` and it is safe to press `y`. Otherwise, or if you're unsure, press `n`.

Comment: To start with, which Ubuntu release number is iinstalled?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Right now, my nginx isn't running, and my server seems to run ok. Are you saying it is safe to remove nginx entirely?

Answer (score 0):

Change your nginx ports in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` (search `listen`) and all other files in that folder or Apache default port in the `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` file (the `Listen` line).